# Duda sobre las listas en asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Buenas soy nuevo en ASP.net en el cual me estoy centrando en el MVC. Aquí muestro el siguiente código.

```
public class ClientesController : Controller
{

    public List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>();

    // GET: Cliente
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Nuevos_Clientes()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult VerDatos()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Post de Venta
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Nuevos_Clientes(String nombre, String apellidos, String dni, int edad)
    {
        clientes.Add(new Cliente(nombre, apellidos, dni, edad));

        return View("VerDatos", clientes);
    }
```

Lo que intento hacer es crear una lista de objetos de tipo cliente y mediante un formulario que se ve reflejado en el método de acción "Nuevos_Clientes" paso por parámetro los siguientes datos (nombre, apellidos, dni y edad). Entonces mi idea como lo muestra el método de acción es que cada vez que de al boton registrar del fomulario se guarde en la lista. Y de hecho eso se realiza, el problema es cuando vuelvo a cargar la pagina (Vista) Nuevos_Clientes según la depuración del código este vuelve a ejecutar la linea donde se crea la lista (new List), perdiendo el objeto que tenia anteriormente, por lo que si dí de alta a un cliente ese registro ya no se mostrara. ¿Entonces como hago para corregir ese problema? Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que declarar la lista `static` para que solo se inicialize una sola instancia de la lista en toda la aplicacion.

Cambia :

```
 public List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>();
```

Por:

```
 public static List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>();
```

Siempre que haces una peticion al controlador, se inicializa una nueva instancia del mismo, lo que significa que todas sus propiedades tendran el valor por defecto en la inicializacion y eso incluye a la lista `clientes`. En otra palabras, siempre que haces una peticion, se crea una nueva instancia de la lista `clientes`. De ahi la necesidad de declarar la lista `static`.

Comment: SI, efectivamente era eso. Muchas gracias por tu aclaración. Intuía que iba por aquí la cosa, pero no estaba seguro. De nuevo gracias.